# Dynamic LINQ .Contains() Throws Timeout expired. Error

Tags: linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

Hey Guys,

I'm working on this query to export some data from a sql 2008 database on vb.net 3.5 website.
I'm using dynamic linq after the inital query to filter down the results based on date, state, country, specialty, and hospital affiliation.

Each of those filter is has a singular value in the query. Except Hospital Affiliation which has a comma delimited list. 
ex: OSUMC, Hospital West, Hopsital East

When filtering, I need to do a .Contains to see if the comma delimted list contains the specific hospital.
ex: (OSUMC, HospitalWest, Hospital East).contains("OSUMC")

If i do a filter on Date, State, Country, and Specialty the query runs perfectly fine. However if I add in a filter for hospital affiliation which is a .Contains() filter then I get Timeout Errors.

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

```
Dim ctx As New OSUMCEntities
    Dim query = (From ca As OSUMCModel.vw_ConferenceAttendance In ctx.vw_ConferenceAttendance Select New With _
                                                                                                     { _
                                                                                                         .LastName = ca.LastName, _
                                                                                                         .FirstName = ca.FirstName, _
                                                                                                         .UserID = ca.UserID, _
                                                                                                         .UserName = ca.Username, _
                                                                                                         .Degree = ca.DegreeName, _
                                                                                                         .Specialty = ca.Specialty, _
                                                                                                         .Profession = ca.Profession, _
                                                                                                         .HospitalAffiliations = ca.HospitalAffiliations, _
                                                                                                         .Address1 = ca.MailingAddress1, _
                                                                                                         .Address2 = ca.MailingAddress2, _
                                                                                                         .City = ca.MailingCity, _
                                                                                                         .State = ca.MailingState, _
                                                                                                         .ZipPostal = ca.MailingZip, _
                                                                                                         .Country = ca.MailingCountry, _
                                                                                                         .ConferenceID = ca.ConfID, _
                                                                                                         .Title = ca.Title, _
                                                                                                         .Date = ca.StartDate, _
                                                                                                         .MaxCredits = ca.Credits, _
                                                                                                         .CreditsAwarded = ca.CreditHours, _
                                                                                                         .CreditsAssignedOn = ca.AssignedOn, _
                                                                                                         .LastUpdated = ca.LastUpdate _
                                                                                                     })
    If (txtDateStart.Text <> "" And txtDateEnd.Text <> "") Then
        Dim StartDate As Date = txtDateStart.Text
        Dim EndDate As Date = txtDateEnd.Text
        query = query.Where("(Date >= @0 And  Date <=@1)", StartDate, EndDate)
    ElseIf (txtDateStart.Text <> "") Then
        Dim StartDate As Date = txtDateStart.Text
        query = query.Where("Date >= @0", StartDate)
    ElseIf (txtDateEnd.Text <> "") Then
        Dim EndDate As Date = txtDateEnd.Text
        query = query.Where("Date <= @0", EndDate)
    End If
    If (ddlState.SelectedValue <> "Export All") Then
        query = query.Where("State = @0", ddlState.SelectedValue)
    End If
    If (ddlCountry.SelectedValue <> "Export All") Then
        query = query.Where("Country = @0", ddlCountry.SelectedValue)
    End If
    If (ddlSpecialty.SelectedValue <> "Export All") Then
        query = query.Where("Specialty = @0", ddlSpecialty.SelectedValue)
    End If
    If (ddlHospitals.SelectedValue <> "Export All") Then
        Dim Hospital As String = ddlHospitals.SelectedValue
        query = query.Where("HospitalAffiliations.Contains(@0)", Hospital)
    End If
```

Comment: try using `.Any` instead of `.Contains`.

Comment: .Any doesn't work on a string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

analyze the query that Linq execute in sql server and check the time in sql profiler.

Comment: Gallmy, thabks for the answer can you tell me how to get the sql query and how to run it it the profiler. I've never done that before.

Comment: plz, look at following links for more information  http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-query-generate-by-linq-to-sql/  http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-t-sql-query-generated-by-linq-to-sql-using-linqpad/

Comment: Galimy, I use the same query in another function but with less variables, I'm only using Hospital Affiliations and userid and the .contains works fine. It only times out when i have all those other variables. Why would it fail on contain but it doesn't fail on any of the equal operators within dynamic linq.

Comment: You should know what exactly query exec in sql server.And try to direct exec it SQl Management studio.It is will help you to understand the problem. iT may be very difficult and slowly to exec query for sql or may be it is problem  with mapping data from sql to Entity or somethins else.

Comment: Galimy, I tried looking up the query in visual studio design mode. But it keep giving me an anonymouse variable explaination, I'm using vb.net. Is there another way to get the query, I'm using SQL server express so I don't have SQL profiler. My real questions is why would it be fine for all the equal operations but no the contains operation.